# Loop over multiple folders from list with glob.glob

Tags: python, csv, glob, shutil

How can I loop over a defined list of folders and all of the individual files inside each of those folders?

I'm trying to have it copy all the months in each year folder. But when I run it nothing happens..

```
import shutil
import glob


P4_destdir = ('Z:/Source P4')

yearlist = ['2014','2015','2016']

for year in yearlist:
    for file in glob.glob(r'{0}/*.csv'.format(yearlist)):
        print (file)
        shutil.copy2(file,P4_destdir)
```

Comment: You can use [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.walk) for this.

Comment: What directory are you running your script *from*? Do directories `2014`, `2015`, and `2016` exist in that directory? If not, specify them as absolute paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem might be that you require a `/` in you source path:

```
import shutil
import glob


P4_destdir = ('Z:/Source P4/')

yearlist = ['2014','2015','2016'] # assuming these files are in the same directory as your code.

for year in yearlist:
    for file in glob.glob(r'{0}/*.csv'.format(yearlist)):
        print (file)
        shutil.copy2(file,P4_destdir)
```

Another thing that might be a problem is if the destination file does not yet exist. You can create it using `os.mkdir`:

```
import os

dest = os.path.isdir('Z:/Source P4/') # Tests if file exists
if not dest:
    os.mkdir('Z:/Source P4/')
```